# Pass value to chained function from for loop

Tags: javascript, callback, raphael

If I have chained functions, as such, and want to run them in a for loop... How can I ensure the context is maintained when the chained callback function is called?

You can see below, `console.log(children[i])` outputs a value when the for loop is started, but undefined in the callback:

```
api.drawConnection = function (fromNode, toNode, bool) {
     if (bool) {
        var children = fromNode.getChildren();
        var node = null;
        var valX, valY = 0;
        node = fromNode;
        valX = 50;
        valY = 35;                                  
    //resize all node distances as children gets bigger...
     if (children.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            valX+=50;
            var connectPath = canvas.path("M " + node.x + " " + node.y + " z"); 
            log(children[i]); //outputs value
            children[i].set.animate({
                cx:  node.shape.attrs.cx-valX/children.length,
                cy:  node.shape.attrs.cy+valY, 
                x : node.shape.attrs.cx-valX/children.length,
                y: node.shape.attrs.cy+valY
            }, 1000, "backOut", function () {
                log(children[i]); //outputs undefined
                connectPath.animate({
                    path: ("M " + fromNode.shape.attrs.cx + " " + (fromNode.shape.attrs.cy+10) + " L " + children[i].shape.attrs.cx + " " + children[i].shape.attrs.cy + " z")
                }, 1000);
            });
        }   
      ...
```

I am using RaphaelJS, btw.

Comment: need a closure ,the for loop will be long completed when your callbacks fire so `i` isn't what you expect it to be

Comment: @charlietfl I thought about that. I'm brand new to the concept of closures... how would I edit this to be in closure form?

Comment: one way is wrap everything inside the loop with `(function(i){ /* code*})(i);`

Comment: @charlietfl this works! But why?? I've been reading up on closures, here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures, and why this works doesn't make sense. Why are you passing in `i` to the self executing function wrapper?

Comment: because it is now an isolated variable inside that function when you pass it in as argument